# ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1 when using OpenPyXl

Tags: python

i have been using Python for Finance, by Yves Hilpisch, specifically chapter 12 as a guide to learning how to integrate Excel and Python. I am currently learning how to use OpenPyxl. However the code that i have directly copied from the book isnt working and i keep getting a ValueError. Here is the code that i am using:

```
#use openpyxl and numpy
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as oxl

#create workbook object
wb = oxl.Workbook()
#create worksheet object
ws = wb.create_sheet(index=0, title='oxl_sheet')
#create data array
data = np.arange(1, 65).reshape((8, 8))
#write bulk data to worksheet
for c in range(data.shape[0]):
    for r in range(data.shape[1]):
        ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = data[c, r]
        # creates a Cell object and assigns a value
#save and close workbook
wb.save('oxl_book.xlsx')
```

And here is the error that i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test1.py", line 14, in <module>
ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = data[c, r]
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 307,in cell raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1
```

I am using python 2.7, could that be the problem?
I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: I believe col & row values start at 1 for excel, so doing something like `for c in range(number)` starts at 0, triggering the ValueError.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, you need to start rows and columns at 1 for excel instead of 0 (which is what happens with `range`).

This worked for me:

```
for c in range(1, data.shape[0] + 1):
    for r in range(1, data.shape[1] + 1):
        ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = data[c - 1, r - 1]
```

Also, I know you can write an entire array at once (which is much, much faster than cell by cell) using excel with python win32com, so I'm sure openpyxl has some functionality there as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your Help. Worked perfectly. while python starts at 0, excel starts at 1. I will be sure to keep that in mind for the next time. Great lesson to learn. I will look into python win32com.  thanks.

Comment: @Rsaha No problem! Also, just stick to openpyxl :P

Comment: Thanks, i have enough trouble as it is with openpyxl. :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I just realized that when you are using openpyxl with an excel file the row start from 1 and column start from 0. So if you want to check cell A1, it will be column 0 and row 1.</strike>

Is this correct analysis?

Sorry I was wrong. The column and row starts from 1. I actually was looping through row by row where it was converting all the elements of the row in a tuple and its index was starting from 0.