# ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm reasonably new to python. I'm trying to get a simple code to get a single column of data, into 4 other columns leaving the data intact in column A. i.e. A1=B1, A2=C1, A3=D1, A4=E1, and then repeat on number 4, A5=B2, A6=C2, A7=D2...

I've tried just putting in numbers i.e. 2, 10 or 100 into my "row" counter so I am definitely above 1. This didn't help as he/she had a zero in the code [ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1 when using OpenPyXl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102690/valueerror-row-or-column-values-must-be-at-least-1-when-using-openpyxl).

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Output.xlsx')
Sheet1 = wb["Sheet1"]

row = 1
count = 1

for row in range(Sheet1.max_row):
    Sheet1.cell(row=count, column=2).value = Sheet1.cell(row, column=1).value
    Sheet1.cell(row=count, column=3).value = Sheet1.cell(row=row+1, column=1).value
    Sheet1.cell(row=count, column=4).value = Sheet1.cell(row=row+2, column=1).value
    Sheet1.cell(row=count, column=5).value = Sheet1.cell(row=row+3, column=1).value
    row += 4
    count += 1

wb.save('Output.xlsx')
wb.close
```

The error I get which I understand but they should always be above 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Output Sorting.py", line 9, in <module>
    Sheet1.cell(row=row, column=2).value = Sheet1.cell(row, column=1).value
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 296, in cell
    raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1
```

The code in this file, line 295 & 296 is:

```
if row < 1 or column < 1:
            raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
```

Am I missing something really basic?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Openpyxl indexes starting at 1, in Python range will start at 0. If you change your for loop to the following, it should work.

```
for row in range(1,Sheet1.max_row+1):
```

Comment: Thought I should add, the code in my question (even once modified) doesn't do what I described originally, but the answer above helps get past the issue I was experiencing. My row += 4 should be deleted and add it in the for loop line like "for row in range(1,Sheet1.max_row+1,4):". Hope this helps.